# Does a github deploy key (ssh key) need to be minted on the intended server or can I do it locally?

Tags: ssh, github-actions, ssh-keys

When I mint an ssh key locally the fingerprint/pub key are trailed with my_email@my_machine.

```
ssh-ed25519 AAA...xyz my_email@my_machine.net
```

For instance.

I'll upload this to GitHub deploy key and the private key to my K8s server. But I'm not sure if that tail bit is relevant.

I assume this is pulled by ssh-keygen from some config on my machine.

What is this tail end of the pub key? And can I avoid it while still minting the keys locally?

Comment: Looks like it's just a helpful comment, which I can alter with `-C`. Not strictly telling of which machine minted it.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm not sure if that tail bit is relevant.

It should not be relevant for unencrypted keys.
As noted in "[Where does SSH agent get the names it uses for keys?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/376061/7490)":

> `ssh-add` attempts to read the comment in the private key file. If it fails, it uses the filename as a comment for further prompts:

But in your case (GitHub deploy key), this should not matter.
Therefore, that comment bit (the `==...` trailing part of the public SSH key) can be ignored.